# How to deal with Relational Data in nested 1-to-1 objects in Room (Convert ForeignKey to Object)

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

Let's say I have an `Order` and a `User` `Entity` that resembles something like this:

`User.java`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey    
    public long id;
    @NonNull    
    public String username;
}
```

`Order.java`:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
                                  parentColumns = "id",
                                  childColumns = "user_id",
                                  onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                                  onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices = @Index("user_id"))
public class Order {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    public long userId;
    @Ignore
    private User user;
}
```

So this way, I have an `Order` with a `User` inside it, on the database I am only saving this relation with the user id as a `Foreign Key` and not the object itself (it's `@Ignore`d), so everything is nice and relational and can be expanded to be used with other types in several different ways and queries and etc.

Now, the question is, **how do I get an `Order` with the `User` object automatically populated by Room inside it?**

If I use `@Embedded`, then `Order` and `User` will live on the same table, which is not good for relational separation of the types. I could return them both together with a `JOIN` but still this only works for data types that have different names (maybe they both have a column named "description"?), besides, inserting an `Order` with a `User` inside it wont be simple with a `JOIN`. `@Relation` only works for one-to-many and it needs a `List`, which is not my case.

I thought that maybe a `@TypeConverter` would be the best option here, converting between `long` and `User`, but this also is tricky. The `@TypeConverter` would need a reference to the `DAO` so it could query the `User` and the `@TypeConverter` is a static method, invoked by Room, so passing the `DAO` can be tricky and lead to many code smells, besides this extra query for each `User` would trigger multiple searches that won't be in the same `@Transaction`.

I am new to Room, but I bet there's a proper way to fix this, to use Room with relational types as it was intended to be used, I just can't find out how to make this work simply and nicely nor I can find it in any documentations.

Comment: IMHO, using `@Embedded` is the easiest way to do 1:1 mapping. most of time Room database just play as like a snapshot of the server response, and rarely do business logic upon it, which is the responsibility of the server, so why do we need such relational separation?

Comment: Because sometimes the same data will be in different server responses, so if we create one table for each response, we will be wasting storage space, for example, `Order` might have a `User` inside it, but `Shopping Cart` also might have `User` inside it. So we will have the same `User` on two different tables? What if the `User` changes his name and we get the update on the Shopping Cart page of the app, but then the user goes offline? We will have the user shown with the old name in the Order page. If we try to synchronize this by hand will he a mess without relational separation

Comment: this makes sense!

Comment: The only option I see for now is to use @embedded and separate the objects in the query so they update, insert and select from separate tables, this way at least I think we can count on relational isolation and getting automatic updates from Room when the data chenfes (not sure about this one with complex queries though)

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the question is, how do I get an Order with the User object automatically populated by Room inside it?

I think there is not an out of box solution for this.

IMHO, the entity model (i.e. the `Order` mapping a FK with `User.id`) **should not be propagated to upper layer** like domain/presentation layer, providing a **`DataMapper`** to transform the entity model to a domain model (i.e. a `User` contains an `Order`) for the upper layer may be a better option.

Comment: That's not correct, you have to propagate the FK, otherwise how could you save that entity back on the database again, if you chance any of it's values? If you remove the FK you remove the link with the database

Comment: I don't get the meaning of `propagate the FK`.

Comment: You are said the FK has to be removed from the object that the database returned right?

Comment: No, i mean keep your current modeling, and create an other pojo for query result using @Relation, and then transform this pojo to what you want in upper layer.

Comment: This gets a lot more complicated when using Room to return `DataSource.Factory`. You will have to make your own to convert the values, instead of using the one provided by the framework.... much more trouble for not so much more return IMHO

Comment: What about `Flowable`, I think using `LiveData` in data layer is not quite helpful.

Comment: Than you will loose the benefits of LiveData in the UI layer, or lose performance doing convertions. You are not supposed to use LiveData in the Data Layer, but using Room in the Data Layer you don't have to touch any of the LiveData it returns, just forward it to the UI.

Comment: Hope [this](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c) can change your mind. Using RxJava in data layer and LiveData in presentation layer is quite a good solution now IMHO.

Comment: Again, that case doesn't cover `PagedList` with `DataSource.Factory` automatically managed by Room and the Paging library.

Comment: You mean `PagedList` with RxJava support doesn't managed by Room automatically? any reference?

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data you can get automatically a `DataSource.Factory` from Room and just pass it to your higher layers, you can make this so transparent only the UI layer will see and use the `LiveData`. You could ask for an `RxJava` version of the `PagedList` from the `DataSource.Factory`, but why bother if you don't even have to touch it until the UI?